# Changing default sorting behavior of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have a table in my database.

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rollno | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name   | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| marks  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

By default if I query

```
select * from students;
```

Shows result sorted by `id INT (auto-increment)`.

```
+----+--------+------------+-------+
| id | rollno | name       | marks |
+----+--------+------------+-------+
|  1 |     65 | John Doe   |    89 |
|  2 |     62 | John Skeet |    76 |
|  3 |     33 | Mike Ross  |    78 |
+----+--------+------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to change default sorting behaviour and make `rollno` the default sorting field, how do I do this?

Comment: Just ORDER BY the thing you want to ORDER BY

Comment: In my situation I need to sort it by rollno most of the time so I want if it is stored in that order by default I won't have to sort in each query.

Comment: What you are asking for is essentially not possible. This would require the table to be constantly resorted on each update, which any SQL engine simply will not do for obvious reasons. There is a lot more complexity in doing that than there is in simply adding an `ORDER BY` onto your query.

Comment: In my condition inserts/updates are quite less as compared to selects that's why I want to persist modified sorting.

Comment: There's no point to it. Mysql (nor any other DBMS) will not persist sorting on a table. You could technically run `ALTER TABLE students ORDER BY rollno ASC;` after every insert/update, but you would take a huge performance hit as opposed to just sorting the results of a `select`. Which is more expensive, sorting an entire table, or sorting only the result of a `select` statement? What is stopping you from just adding `order by` to your `select` statement?

Comment: @ElGavilan i get your point now, I thought because of less inserts/updates permanent modified would be better.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I believe that you could achieve this with a view. E.g. CREATE VIEW ordered as SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY whatever - but I really cannot see an advantage to it.

Answer (score 5):

#### There is no default sort order!

The DB returns the data in the fastest way possible. If this happen to be the order in which it is stored or a key is defined then this is up to the system. You can't rely on that.

Think about it: Why would the DB use performace to order something by default if you don't need it ordered. DBs are optimised for speed.

If you want it being ordered then you have to specify that in an `order by` clause.

Comment: In my situation I need to sort it by rollno most of the time so I want  if it is stored in that order by default I won't have to sort in each query.

Comment: You don't understand. You can't rely on any default order. If you want it ordered - add an `order by` clause. Otherwise don't. That is the only way of ordering relyable.

Answer (score 1):

Run this

`ALTER TABLE students ORDER BY rollno ASC;`

Comment: This will only sort existing data in the table; it will not maintain the sort order in the table if rows are added or changed. You should never rely on the assumption that data in a table is already presorted.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but as @ElGavilan said what about future inserts/updates?

Comment: Databases are optimized for speed not for order. It is much faster to only have to sort the result of a `select` than it is to consistently sort the entire contents of a table.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from students order by rollno asc;` will return your results sorted by that column. It should be noted that there is no default sorting behavior as far as data is actually stored in the database (aside from identities and indexes); you should never depend on your results being sorted a certain way unless you explicitly sort them (using `order by`).